# Scaling elements in Mozilla not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm trying to create an effect (color rounded blackground which fades in half a second) when pressing an icon in my application; so basically I use :active pseudo class and make the span above the icon twice bigger and rounder, and at the same time making the icon twice smaller (to counter the effect). I got this working good on Chrome and IE, but somehow Mozilla make the icon smaller at the end of the :active transformation (just for a moment). How could I eliminate this?

```
.collapse-btn {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 9;
     right: 16;
     background: $white;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-transition: background-color .5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color linear;
    transition: background-color .5s linear;

   &:active{
     -moz-transform: scale(2,2);
     -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
     transform: scale(2,2);
     background-color: #c7c7c7;

   svg {
      -moz-transform-origin: center center;
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
      transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
      -moz-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Provide some more code, i.e. html, css, javascript. Code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: Added React code used for the components @VilasKumkar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! It's a big of a hack but works... If the svg class is 'icon':

```
svg.icon {
      -moz-transform: scale(1,1)
}
```

Somehow the transform CSS attribute is not apply on every level of the tree at the same time, so making a trick like re-scaling at the end can solve the problem.